# Is there a "with... as..." clause in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my use case

```
<li ng-repeat="item in heterogeneousFruitArray">
  <div ng-if="item.type == 'apple'">
    ... custom apple stuff ...
  </div>
  <div ng-if="item.type == 'orange'">
    ... custom orange stuff ...
  </div>
  ... stuff for all fruits ...
</li>
```

It would increase readability if I could say

```
<li ng-repeat="item in heterogeneousFruitArray">
  <div ng-if="item.type == 'apple'">

    <span ng-with="item as apple">
       <h1>{{apple.name}}</h1>
       Crispness: {{apple.crispness}}
       ... and so on...
    </span>

  </div>
  ...
</li>
```

Is there a way to do this with angular?

I realize that this pattern could be me coding with an accent because of my django templates background.  If I'm miles away from 'how it's done in angular', please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

`ngInit` was designed with aliasing in mind, especially within an `ngRepeat`:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in heterogeneousFruitArray">
  <div ng-if="item.type == 'apple'" ng-init="apple=item">
    ... custom apple stuff ...
  </div>
  <div ng-if="item.type == 'orange'" ng-init="orange=item"">
    ... custom orange stuff ...
  </div>
  ... stuff for all fruits ...
</li>
```

Here is official documentation on [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIGn9ZSp29OjQzWsDCBj?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm.. that's a pretty strong warning.  Otherwise it looks like it does  pretty much if not exactly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: I think improving readability with aliasing was what the angular team intended. You're using it properly IMO. In other posts, I've seen it misused more often than not.

Comment: @Ted _that's a pretty strong warning_ If you are "scared" of `ng-init` you can use `<span ng-if="item == 'apples' && (apple = item)">` Now it depends what is more readable for you...

Answer (score 1):

In tandem with `ngInit` for aliasing, you should also consider using `ngSwitch`, instead of having multiple `ngIf`s where only one is evaluated to `true` at a time.
Using `ngSwitch` has the same result, but increases readability and is more efficient as it evaluates the condition once in every digest loop (in contrast to multiple `ngIf`s where the same expression is evaluated once for every `ngIf`).

E.g.:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in heterogeneousFruitArray">
    <div ng-switch="item.type">

        <!-- Apple-specific template -->
        <span ng-switch-when="apple" ng-init="apple=item">
            <h1>{{apple.name}}</h1>
            Crispness: {{apple.crispness}}
        </span>

        <!-- Orange-specific template -->
        <span ng-switch-when="orange" ng-init="orange=item">
            <h1>{{orange.name}}</h1>
            Juicy-ness: {{orange.juicyness}}
        </span>

        <!-- Default template (used when `item.type` is unknown/unexpected) -->
        <span ng-switch-default ng-init="unknown=item">
            <h3>What kind of fruit is "{{unknown.type}}" ???</h3>
        </span>

    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [AngularJS Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to implement that.

Html:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='item in items | filter:{name: "orange"}'>
            {{item.id}} - {{item.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
        {
            id: 12,
            name: 'apple'
        },
        {
            id: 13,
            name: 'orange'
        },
        {
            id:14,
            name:'grape'
        }
    ];
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygz2Y/).

Comment: Link-only answers rot. Put an example as well as the link here.

Comment: The filter approach doesn't seem to work for this use case -- i need to be able to go apple, orange, apple, apple, orange, apple, grape, grapefruit, orange, apple -- in that order.

Comment: Then create your own custom filter.

Comment: I don't think you understood the use case:  I want to rename objects for readability.  I don't want to only show a subset of objects, or rename all objects.  Providing a solution that doesn't solve the given use case, then saying "write your own code" is about as far from helpful as I can imagine.

Comment: Your main question isn't clear at all and only now I really understood what you really wanted, so first of all your in javascript and it does not matter if you are accessing an apple’s property or an orange’s property. In my opinion it won’t increase readability if you added an ng-with and won’t really increase your functionality. Using ng-init doesn't increase readability and doesn't increase functionality as well.

Comment: If you want to be extra organized and readable maybe you will need to create a directive that will render your array(ted-fruit-array). The directive will dynamically go through your array (in javascript) and create html with sub directives(e.g. ted-apple, ted-orange etc.). After the html is ready, you will compile it and inject it into your dom.
Now, you will implement an extra directive per fruit and use your own properties there.
Is this solution work all the work? I doubt it. Will it be more readable\extensible? Yes.